# Set grid row/column sizes dynamically with animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Let's assume a page to have two grid rows similar to the picture. The first row contains a DataGrid and the second row has a custom control attached.

[image: DataGrid and custom control on a page]

The DataGrid row is usually stretched over the whole page and the second row is hidden by default by some bool in the page's view model.
I now want to achieve to resize the second row height and affect the height of the first row, too.
This way if there is a lot of content in the DataGrid it can be viewed with a scrollbar.

The row definitions are like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ControlHeight}" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The control is attached like this:

```
<local:CustomControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SomeControl"
                     local:AnimateSlideInFromBottomMarginProperty.Value="{Binding ControlVisible}" />
```

The `AnimateSlideInFromBottomMarginProperty` is an animation I wanted to couple the whole resize process with, but I currently have no idea how to.

The custom control is not visible to the view model to somehow attach the animation code wise.
My best bet right now is to have a property `ControlHeight` that changes on some button click command. But I'm not happy that I set it to some value (e.g. 300) instead of knowing the `Auto` size the control would actually need.

Here are the command methods:

```
public void OpenControl()
{
    ControlVisible = true;
    ControlHeight = 300;
}

public void CloseControl()
{
    ControlVisible = false;
    ControlHeight = 0;
}
```

Maybe someone has a nice idea on how to
1. Changing the property to behave like a double animation accelerating
1.1 Or maybe something completely different and more elegant
2. Give the view model maybe the `Auto` size of the custom control and set/increase from 0 to `Auto`.
2.1 Or maybe, you guessed it, something completely different and more elegant

If I need to make the issue any clearer please let me know.

Comment: First thing I would consider is setting the rowdefinition to auto of that second row. Then you can animate the height of the customcontrol and the row will respond. Have you considered animating the scalex of the custom control? You then have fixed values of from 0 to 1 and it can be a storyboard in xaml with a data or event trigger to run it.

Comment: Wow yes I have overseen that way. Duh.
I have tried to set several height properties before but not the one of the control.
So right now the grid is resized correctly which is very much what I need. Now I think I'll think of some animation for this and it's good to go.
If I'm quick enough I could answer this myself later :)